# How can Site-to-Site & Point-to-Site be established using single EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn

Details :

I am trying to connect AWS & Azure infrastructure together. I have one EC2 instance running in AWS & Azure virtual network gateway configured in Azure. How can I configure the same EC2 instance (one) for P2S & S2S connection both. So that the remote user connected to EC2 instance can also access Azure resources. To minimize cost I am trying to use only one machine for both P2s & S2S.

Site to site connection is to be established between AWS & Azure virtual network gateway. Point to site connection is to be established between remote users and AWS EC2 instance.

which opensource VPN software/technology can be used for this purpose on EC2.

Can single EC2 machine be used to establish P2S & S2S simultaneously ?
I have azure gateway configured on other side, not many VPN software support connecting to azure gateway or not documented

Answer (score 0):

Your question is almost close what was clearly documented in the blog,

https://aws.amazon.com/answers/networking/aws-multiple-vpc-vpn-connection-sharing/

Instead of VPC, you need to connect to another VPN site.

Also you need to notice it is a single point of failure. If EC2 goes down, you will not access to any of those sites. Other than accessing them through other routes.

The opensource software we use for vpn is,

https://openvpn.net/

Hope it helps.